# How to Pressed button and run animacion in unity (NO CLICK, JUST Pressed)

Tags: javascript, c#, animation, unity-game-engine

ON Pressed button run animcion

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrY0p.png)

Comment: You need to explain your problem better, as if there is no image.  Please give a full description.

Comment: What does javascript doing in tags? Unity has nothing to do with javascript ...

Comment: @m.rogalski Unity also supports, and is partially documented in, javascript actually

Comment: @Shogunivar I dont know where you have seen this but read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html). Unity has never been using javascript. This is called UnityScript and it's syntax is based on javascript. It's the same as you would say that unity's scripting language is C or C++ because C# was based on these languages...

Comment: @m.rogalski if you go to the scripting reference (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html) they refer to the code examples being in **C#** or **javascript**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I assume you want to :

1. Start an animation when the mouse button is pressed down
2. Stop the animation when the mouse button is released

You can use [Event Trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-EventTrigger.html) to do so. Here is an example to do this in code :

```
// Drag & Drop the button into the inspector
public Button button ;

// Drag & Drop your animator into the inspector
public Animator animator ;

void Start( )
{
    EventTrigger eventTrigger = button.AddComponent<EventTrigger>( );

    // Detect when mouse button is pressed down
    EventTrigger.Entry pointerDownEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry( );
    pointerDownEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
    pointerDownEntry.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { OnPointerDown( (PointerEventData)data ); } );
    eventTrigger.triggers.Add( pointerDownEntry );

    // Detect when mouse button is released
    EventTrigger.Entry pointerUpEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry( );
    pointerUpEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
    pointerUpEntry.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { OnPointerUp( (PointerEventData)data ); } );
    eventTrigger.triggers.Add( pointerUpEntry );
}

public void OnPointerDown( PointerEventData data )
{
    Debug.Log( "OnPointerDown called." );

    // Stop your animation, supposing you have a bool parameter in your animator
    animator.SetBool("boolName", true);
}

public void OnPointerUp( PointerEventData data )
{
    Debug.Log( "OnPointerUp called." );

    // Stop your animation, supposing you have a bool parameter in your animator
    animator.SetBool("boolName", false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much it's work